# Python - Novice: Why this simple if-elif (replication of the C case block) always produces the same result?

Tags: python, if-statement

beginner here.  Could anyone explain and/or help me revise this Python code to produce the correct output, whenever I enter the string specified?  For example, if March is inputted, output "02".  Currently, the program always outputs 00, for January, no matter the input.  Here is the code:

```
x = raw_input("Starting Month: ")

if x == "January" or "january":
   stMonth = '00'
elif x == "February" or "february":
    stMonth = '01'
elif x == "March" or "march":
    stMonth = '02'
elif x == "April" or "april":
    stMonth = '03'
elif x == "May" or "may":
    stMonth = '04'
elif x == "June" or "june":
    stMonth = '05'
elif x == "July" or "june":
    stMonth = '06'
elif x == "August" or "august":
    stMonth = '07'
elif x == "September" or "september":
    stMonth = '08'
elif x == "October" or "october":
    stMonth = '09'
elif x == "November" or "november":
    stMonth = '10'
elif x == "December" or "december":
    stMonth = '11'
else:
    print "error"
print stMonth
```

---

Output:

```
$ python month.py 
Starting Month: march
00
```

Thanks in advance - any and all help is much, much appreciated!

Comment: btw this is not a great way to do lookups, you want a map of month name to month number, e.g. `month_map = {'january' => '01', ...}` then you can do `print month_map[x.lower()]`, alternate is to create list of all names and return `index + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work as expected is because,

```
if x == "January" or "january":
```

is equivalent to:

```
if x == "January" or True:
```

and the first `if` statement will always be `True`.

```
>>> x = 'january'
>>> if x:
...     print x
...     
january
>>>
```

---

Convert the input string to lowercase using `.lower()` function, it would make it easier.

```
x = raw_input("Starting Month: ").lower()

if x == "january":
   stMonth = '00'
elif x == "february":
    stMonth = '01'
elif x == "march":
    stMonth = '02'
elif x == "april":
    stMonth = '03'
elif x == "may":
    stMonth = '04'
elif x == "june":
    stMonth = '05'
elif x == "june":
    stMonth = '06'
elif x == "august":
    stMonth = '07'
elif x == "september":
    stMonth = '08'
elif x == "october":
    stMonth = '09'
elif x == "november":
    stMonth = '10'
elif x == "december":
    stMonth = '11'
else:
    print "error"
print stMonth
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `or` has higher precedence than `==`: `x == 'january' or 'January'` is effectively the same as `(x == 'january') or 'January'`, and as `'January'` evaluates to `true`,  the combined statement is always true.

You should change each statement to `x == 'january' or x == 'January'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement:

```
if x == "January" or "january":
```

Is always returning true because its evaluated as:

is x == "January" No
   Then or is evaluated and it check january and it returns true. So if you try:
   if "january":
   it always returns your true and hence you get 00 as output.

You either use or or IN clause like:

```
if x == "January" or x == "january":
```

or

```
if x in ("January", "january"):
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `"january"` evaluates to `True`, check this out:

```
In [1]: x = 'march'

In [2]: if x == "January" or "january":
   ...:        stMonth = '00'
   ...:     

In [3]: stMonth
Out[3]: '00'

In [4]: bool("january")
Out[4]: True
```

You probably want:

```
x == "January" or x == "january":
    stMonth = '00'
```

or even better:

```
x.lower() == "january":
    stMonth = '00'
```

Comment: @TheNOvice, `"january"` is a non-emtpy string, any non-empty string evaluates to `True`. In your second part of the `if statement` you are not testing whether `x == "january"`, you are testing whether "january" in a non-emtpy string.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear your doubt, fix your code like this:

```
if x == "January" or x == "january":
   stMonth = '00'
elif x == "February" or x == "february":
    stMonth = '01'
```